# How to trigger a function when control c is pressed in c++

Tags: c++

I'm wondering how could I trigger a function when control + c is pressed but I want it not only in the program window but outside the window like in a browser, text pad and etc. Help would be appreciated.
This would be in C++
Thanks

Comment: Please confirm my following understanding: 
You need to execute a function when `<CTRL>+C` is pressed anywhere in the system while your application is running. Also your application is running on Windows operating system.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this on Windows:

```
char input = _getch();
    
if (input == '\x3')
{
    std::cout << "Ctrl C pressed!" << std::endl;
    //...
}
```

The above code will print "Ctrl C pressed!" when input == '\x3' (Control C).

### Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

void foo(char character)
{
    std::cout << character << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        char input = _getch();

        if (input == '\x3')
        {
            foo(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are making the assumption that this is on windows and also this doesn't qualify for OP's requirement that it should work also when done outside the program's window.

Comment: Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-170 says that `_getch` cannot be used to read CTRL+C.

Comment: It can be used to read Ctrl + C. You should try the code out for yourself.

Comment: I don't have a system to test it, but seems that the documentation is wrong or unclear, so I removed my downvote: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/433196/-getch-and-ctrl-c.html

Comment: @user17732522 Alright :)

Comment: Still as @user17732522 pointed out this doesn't seem to be the original requirement.